# How to make the tank look to the side of the mouse and shoot where the player clicks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a tank in a 3rd person 3D game so my camera is looking at the tank from above and a bit from the side. I need the turret of my tank to rotate on the y-axis so that it always looks at the mouse and shoot where the player clicks. The problem is that my game is 3D and all I get is that it actually looks at the mouse (like upwards to the sky).

This is the code I have now:

```
private Vector3 target;
    private Camera cam;

    private void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = new Vector2();
        mousePos.x = Input.mousePosition.x;
        mousePos.y = Input.mousePosition.y;
        target = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, cam.nearClipPlane));
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
```

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` ... `unityscript` is/was a JavaScript flavor like custom language previously used by Unity and is long deprecated by now

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here: `target = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, cam.nearClipPlane));`

What you actually need to do is generate a ray that comes out of the camera with ScreenPointToRay(), then do a Physics.Raycast() with that ray and get the RaycastHit from it. Then set the target equal to the RaycastHit.

For example:

```
Ray screenRay;
RaycastHit screenRayHit;

float maxRaycastDistance;

screenRay = cam.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);

if(Physics.Raycast(screenRay, out screenRayHit, maxRaycastDistance))
{
    target = screenRayHit;
}
else
{
    //just sets the turret to aim at the endpoint of the ray if you aim at nothing
    target = screenRay.GetPoint(maxRaycastDistance);
}
```

Comment: Well I think the code I wrote should be working to give you a proper target. Make sure the barrel of the turret is running along its z axis (or "forward" axis) because transform.LookAt() points the forward vector toward the target. Basically, when you click on the turret in the editor, the blue arrow should be parallel with the barrel.

Comment: Yea I know, the thing is that it is located correctly on the axes.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with it?